# Python 3 Regex - Extracting an unknown substring from a sentence with unknown spacing between strings

Tags: regex, string, substring, character, python-3.7

I am trying to extract an unknown substring between two substrings in a sentence, which has a standard design.

Examples :

```
object Ball is located in row 8
objectballisLocatedINROw8
objectChairislocated in row 4
    object CupboardisLocated in row 22
```

In the sentences above the statements follow a specific pattern like below :

`object<optional spacing>item-name<optional spacing>is<optional spacing>located<optional spacing>in<optional spacing>row<optional spacing>some integer`

Also the substrings can have weird cases like fully upper case, fully lowercase or a mix of both upper and lower cases in an unpredictable manner (please refer the example sentences above to know what I mean).

**My goal :**

Extract `item-name` where `item-name` could be any unknown string in unknown case (upper, lower, mix of both)

**What I tried ?**

```
import re

task = "objectChairislocatedinrow8"
object = re.search(r'(\s)*object(\s)*[a-z]*(\s)*is(\s)*located(\s)*in(\s)*row(\s)*\d+(\s)*', 
task, re.IGNORECASE)

print(object)
```

Comment: Your regex is fine, you just need to remove the capturing groups around spaces and add one around the `item-name` part of the string: https://regex101.com/r/PAIzzJ/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regex**: `'^ *object *([A-Za-z]+) *is.*'`

It matches words with both upper and lowercase words. It also work is the word has 'is' in the middle of it, like *this* or *paris* The parenthesis around [A-Za-z]+ select that group so it can be used later.

```
import re

task = "objectChairislocatedinrow8"
object = re.search(r'^ *object *([A-Za-z]+) *is.*', 
task, re.IGNORECASE)

print(object.group(1))
```

output:

```
Chair
```